How to properly type keyword-only function arguments
Well considering the following code:
from typing import Callable

def delete_test_user_description(*, request: int | None = None) -> str:
    """Get a string indicating which users will be deleted

    :return str: indication of which users will be deleted
    """
    return "ok"
    
COMMAND_DESCRIPTIONS: dict[str, Callable[[int | None], str]] = {
    "Delete test users": delete_test_user_description,
}

MyPy (and other typing checkers) will give an error about the type of the argument to the function. However if I remove the * symbol, yet keep the function usage exactly the same, it works.
How would I properly type this? For MyPy there exists obviously the extension DefaultNamedArg, however this results in kind of weird looking code. But moreover, this is mypy only. Is this use not covered by the typing pep?

Why should that not be rejected? The function takes only a keyword argument, but the dictionary requires values with a positional argument. Then if you allow the function to take it positionally there's no conflict. The docs explicitly mention the limitations of Callable and suggest alternatives.
